# accessing main window in QGIS when processing modeller is active

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

While working on a model in the processing modeler I can't enter the main GUI.

Every time I want to check some features or layer properties I have to leave the modeller, do the check and reopen the model I'm working on.

Is there a way to swith between the modeller and the main window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modeler is a modal dialog, i.e. the user cannot interact with anything else while it is open. As far as I know, this behavior can not be changed by the user. In my opinion, it would be nice to turn the modeler into a non-modal dialog. I don't see a reason why it has to be modal.

Comment: It's already been fixed for 3.0

Comment: @ndawson: great! I'm looking forward to the release...